# Change Server IP and SQL Server Agent Not Execute Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I changed the IP server that I have SQL Server on, now all the jobs I wrote on the old IP server, are not running on the new IP server. I get the error

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 15.0.2000.5 for 64-bit Copyright(c) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73537560/edit) your question to include the complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: After changing to instance's IP address configuration, did you use SQL Server Configuration Manager to restart the SQL Server service, the SQL Server Agent service and the SQL Server Browser service?